# How to block all outbound traffic except Tor

Tags: iptables, firewall, tor

I have tried to use these rules with `iptables` but  after I have used same rules in `ip6tables`, it has blocked everything.

Why do my `ip6tables` rules block everything?

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m owner --uid-owner debian-tor
iptables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o lo
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP


ip6tables -F OUTPUT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -m owner --uid-owner debian-tor
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j ACCEPT -o lo
ip6tables -P OUTPUT DROP
```

Comment: It looks like the issue with your ip6tables rules is that you are using the same rules as for IPv4 (iptables), but IPv6 network communication operates differently and may have different requirements.

Answer (score 0):

To block all outgoing traffic except for Tor on both IPv4 and IPv6, you can use the following rules:

```
iptables -F OUTPUT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner debian-tor -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -j DROP

ip6tables -F OUTPUT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m conntrack --ctstate ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -o lo -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -p icmpv6 -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -m owner --uid-owner debian-tor -j ACCEPT
ip6tables -A OUTPUT -j DROP
```

In the `ip6tables` rules, you have allow outgoing ICMPv6 traffic to ensure that important network protocols like neighbor discovery and router advertisements are still allowed. This is necessary for IPv6 connectivity.

Comment: I  have  tried  these settings but  it  is  still  not  good  when  I  add  IPV6 rules  it  still  blocks  everything could  you  help  me  ?

Comment: @BulcsúÉdes I've edited the post. Try what's in the code block now.

Comment: The  same  as  I  have set IPV6 rules it  has  blocked everything , what  is  the  problem  ?

Comment: Looks like you might have to do some troubleshooting. Check the rules for both tables (`-L -n -v`), remove the rules, and then try adding them one by one to see which of them is causing trouble. Check if the Tor service is running and that it is running as `debian-tor`. Is Tor properly configured? Are you using any VPS/Cloud services or something similar which has its own firewall?

Comment: When  I  set only IPV4 rules it  works  so I think  the  user of service match but when I set IPV6 rules it does  not  work I have just installed Tor by this command   `apt install tor deb.torproject.org-keyring ` I have  not  configured because it has worked  I am using laptop from  my  home  Debian 11 installed on  it

Comment: Or  is  it  enough  if  I  just  block  my  IPv4 traffic  ?

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the  problem was with Firefox  proxy settings :Proxy DNS when  using SOCKS v5 was not checked

And so  the  original iptables's settings work without icmpv6 enabled